# Memory leak UIWebView when loading from file instead of URL?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiwebview

I have a UIViewController that contains a UIWebView (OS 3.0). If I load it with file data, as soon as the 'Back Button' is hit and the view is dismissed, I'm seeing `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`
error with WebCore object releasing 'SharedBuffer'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html"];   
    NSData *fileHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
    [webView loadData:fileHtmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];      
}
```

If I change the above to load via request, everything is fine.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

In my controller's dealloc, I release webview with the following:

```
[webView setDelegate:nil];
[webView release];
```

Stack trace is below:

```
#2  0x359d34ae in WebCore::SharedBuffer::~SharedBuffer
#3  0x358fdab8 in WebCore::DocumentLoader::~DocumentLoader
#4  0x332d3c00 in WebDocumentLoaderMac::~WebDocumentLoaderMac
#5  0x358fec8c in WebCore::FrameLoader::detachFromParent
#6  0x332d8830 in -[WebView(WebPrivate) _close]
#7  0x332d8757 in -[WebView close]
#8  0x332d86db in -[WebView dealloc]
#9  0x35890719 in WebCoreObjCDeallocOnWebThreadImpl
#10 0x358d29ce in HandleWebThreadReleaseSource
```

Is there something else I need to do to prevent the leak/bad_access error?

Comment: Uh, why do you talk of a Leak here? All I see you describing is a crash. Where's the memory leak? (sorry, this should have been posted as comment, not an answer. Too late, one cannot even delete one's own posts after submitting them just a few seconds ago)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you need to do the steps outlined here:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/10741#10741

specifically the suggestion made by Jim:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView.delegate retain];

    // logic ...
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{   
     // logic ...

    [webView.delegate release];
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     // error logic ...
    [webView.delegate release];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if (m_webView.loading)
    {
        [m_webView stopLoading];
    }

     // further logic ...
}

- (void)dealloc {
    m_webView.delegate = nil;
    [m_webView release];
   ...
    [super dealloc];
}
```